# Iterate and Stringify_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Alright, I was very happy iterating over items table when suddenly **BANG!**

```
NoMethodError in Items#index

undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/items/7":String
```

Why like this?

**Item Controller**

```
def index 
  @item = current_user.bar.items.all
end
```

**Item Index View**

```
<% current_user.bar.items.each do |item|%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to(image_tag( item.foto.url.to_s), item.name, item_path(item.id)) %></td>
    </tr >
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the method signature for [link_to](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/00554568e0625b2e4d4212ab7464f02234f74427/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L231).

You're handing it an image, some text, and a path. That's wrong. The reason you're getting that error is because `link_to` thinks that the last argument is an options hash, when really, it's a string (the path). You need to remove the `image_tag`, the `item.name`, or simply provide a block to include them both:

```
<%= link_to item_path(item) do %>
  <%= image_tag(item.foto.url) %> <%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yee! humm interesting, and in fact make sense! thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 1):

Your use of link_to method is not right. It should be something like this (if you want image to be the 'clickable image')

```
<%= link_to image_tag( item.foto.url.to_s), item_path(item.id)) %>
```

Hope it helps.